# Windows Phone 8 - deploy app time out error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winapi, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I just received my Windows Phone, which is running Windows Black. I opened a test app in Visual Studio 2013, but when I deploy app to device I get time out error. The apps run perfectly in emulators including "Emulator 720p", but when I switch it to deploy device, I get an error.

My Setup:

- Windows Studio Professional 2013(Legal Copy)
- Lumia 1520
- Laptop i7/8GB  HHD:40GB(free)

I have 3 USB ports and I get the same error on all 3 ports. I have restarted the pc & phone, multiple times. I have transferred music to the phone through File Explorer and set up the Developers account.

**Note**: I have wrote apps for Windows 8 and 8.1, never had this error, so right now I'm at a stop. All drivers are installed and updated.

**Error**: Error    1   This operation returned because the timeout period expired.     0   0

Comment: "I get an error"... any more details about the error you can share, or is "time out error" the only message?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I updated the post the error is "Error 1 This operation returned because the timeout period expired.  0 0 
"

Comment: @AMR I have used multiple cables. The two that are the newest was my Samsung Galaxy 4 USB Data cable and the cable that came with my Nokia which I only used 4 times, twice since I have wireless charging

Comment: Just mine 5 cents: trying another usb port fixes a problem for me.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko 7Months later and I still have the problem. There's something in the Hyper-V from Visual Studio 203 that causes this problem. When Hyper-V is turned off, I can use any port and any data cord without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
Solution: Unknown, but I can navigate through Phone's folder in explorer to view files versus before when I had to wait up to 5 seconds for the files to show.

I turned off Hyper-V and restarted my PC to install vmware, so maybe it's Hyper-V.

Comment: Hyper-V was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a newer SDK. (I'm not sure there is a newer one).

As I know, Lumia 1520 has a newer OS (newer than 1020 and 920 etc.)

So, I think Microsoft could publish a new SDK for Windows Phone 8.1 (Lumia 1520 should be running with WP8.1 OS)

You can try to remove your device from Device Manager list and add it again, if don't work, you can try on another computer but anyway I don't think these advices are fix your problem.

Wait for the newer SDK.

Comment: Lumia 1520 is on Windows Phone 8. Windows phone 8.1 hasn't been released for cellphones, yet. 8.1 doesn't release until the spring.

Comment: As I remember, Nokia's Lumia 1520 presentation they've said Lumia 1520'll be launched with WP8.1. Am I wrong? Are you sure your phone running WP8?

Comment: 8.1 for Windows Phone has not been released.

Answer (score 0):

I make it work by saving and restarting the app and run again.