# Windows phone 8.0 error 0x89371B01 when trying to deploy app

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I cant find information on this error anywhere. I am connecting to a brand new lumia icon (AKA lumia 929). Dev account is registered. I have attempted:

- reinstalling windows phone SDK
- restarting phone
- restarting computer
- ensured the app runs on the emulators properly. the only required capability of this app is network. Capabilities have not been changed from the defaults since the project was created. none of the manifest xml files have been touched.
- ensured phone software version is up to date
- ensured apphub account is valid and active
- ensured the windows phone developer registration tool worked, unregistered and re-registered the phone to make sure
- restarting the "ip over usb" windows service thingy
- changing the platform built target to ARM or AnyCpu (no difference, same error)
- tried alternate deployment methods such as windows phone power tools (the xap deploy) and I get the same error when trying to connect (so I know it's not an issue with visual studio, nor is it an issue with the app code)
- I can successfully deploy separate code to a separate WP7 device (so I know it's not an issue with the computer)
- tried multiple usb ports
- tried two separate laptops
- tried visual studio 2013 and 2012

The behavior is this:

1. Connect the phone via usb and unlock it
2. Attempt to connect to phone via windows phone power tools OR deploy an app via visual studio
3. System hangs for about 90 seconds and seems to time out
4. Error appears

I am able to view the phone contents, name it and explore it on my laptop, but when it comes time to deploy something I am stuck.

Error message is simply: **0x89371B01**

What does that mean? Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: What does your code look like? Many random errors like this happen for stupid things like missing capabilities or improper set properties.

Comment: This happens when windows is trying to connect to the phone, before I even specify where the code or the xap is located

Comment: Have you registered and unlocked your phone from development?

Comment: Yes I have used the windows phone developer registration tool. I have un-registered and re-registered the phone to ensure it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was able to come up with a repeatable solution for the issue. Im HOPING that by posting this I dont tempt fate and have the phone not work again!

Here are the steps I did to resolve it (not sure if all of them are necessary):

1. On phone, disable wireless
2. Connect phone to laptop
3. Open device manager and click to show ALL HIDDEN DEVICES (including hidden devices is important)
4. Uninstall ALL phone-related devices (one in portable devices, several in USB
   devices) anything that mentions lumia must go
5. Disconnect/reboot phone
6. Reboot laptop (there seems to be a process keeping the port open)

I had connectivity, then I lost it, then I re-gained it using these steps and it seems to be reliable for me (so far)

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the device drivers on your Windows 8.1 machine?  It could be a driver issue with your USB drivers on the computer.

I have also found that, once you get it connected, going into the Device Manager and deleting the device from there and forcing it to reload has helped me in the past.

Comment: If @atley says it then you can rest assured it is as if a Windows Phone Jesus has blessed you with his wisdom /bow

Comment: @atley: the device manager shows the phone three times. deleting the duplicates doesnt seem to have any effect and upon next connection they re-appear.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, try running "sfc /scannow" at a command prompt on the PC.  It may require admin elevation.  I've seen some bizarre behaviors due to dll problems in sxs in win 8.1, wondering if this could be caused by that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

1. Have you installed the [GDR3 Emulators](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41559) and tried running it on the 1080p emulator? It looks like the 929 is a 1920x1080 phone and will have the latest the latest updates installed. First place to check.
2. Based on this feedback in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863630/windows-phone-8-deploy-app-time-out-error) it looks like someone was having a similar issue and disabling Hyper-V resolved it for him. If you disable Hyper-V and it works, try re-enabling it and see if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

jmshapland had the correct answer for me, with the same issue.  Disabling Hyper-V did the trick!  No thanks to microsoft phone dev center forum posting on the issue..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/24bd3e48-e7b4-4d00-8d69-193f49989ce0/0x89731b01-error-during-deploy-to-device?forum=wpdevelop

Looks like I'll be disabling Hyper-V to test on my device, and re-enabling to work in emulator mode:

dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

and

dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All